# Access Denied for the signed URL .NET CloudFront

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to set up a cloudfront for my s3 bucket that will only allow users to read or write with the signed URLs.(read the file, upload, and download)

The S3 doesn't have public read/write permissions.

CloudFront is:
Http and HTTPS.
It has Trusted Signer as self.
It has Restricted View access.
It has a origin domain name as origin-domain-name/public.
Lastly, it has a origin access identity as origin-access-identity/cloudfront/XXXXXXX.

I have my cloudfront pem file and aws private key id.

My c# code to generate signed url is:

```
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../keys/CloudFront-PrivateKey.pem");

var url = AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.GetCannedSignedURL(
            AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.Protocol.http,
            "http://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net",
            sr,
            "public/AddinJudgeIssue.png",
            "<AWS Private Key ID>",
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
```

Each time when I execute the code, it generates the URL. However, when I copy and paste it to URL, it says "access denied".

First of all, does anyone have any idea about why this happening?

Secondly, this works somehow, can I use this same technique to upload assets to the bucket?

Thank you and apologize for my ignorance. I digged the aws whitepapers, but failed to find a straightforward guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudFront/MCloudFrontUrlSignerGetCannedSignedURLCloudFrontUrlSignerProtocolStringFileSystemInfoStringStringDateTime.html) suggests two problems:

`"http://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"` should not include `http://` because the field is `distributionDomain` and expects the domain name, not the base URL.

`"public/AddinJudgeIssue.png"` should have a leading `/` because this field is `resourcePath`.  Paths begin with a `/` even though object keys don't.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some experiment, I got it working. Although I used root credentials and pem keys to generate the signed URL, I still had to give public read/write access to my S3 bucket. That was the reason why I was getting access denied error.  On Cloudfront setup, "restrict bucket access" option gives restriction to my bucket anyway.

Comment: Keep in mind to provide full information, S3 403 will give you 2 request Ids in response and 403 body and there is no need to make bucket public , you can use Origin access identity to allow CloudFront to access S3 whereas Restrict viewer access on CloudFront is only check CloudFront Signed URL.